# Spring MVC + Hibernate App

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp

I have an app (Spring MVC + Hibernate) and AppFuse Framework too.

I have two entities: `User` and `Robot` with a Many-To-One relationship.

I need to add a drop down list to for owner (`User`) to the `Robot` form (robotForm.jsp).

The `Robot` entity has a `User`. I read that I must create a custom `Editor` for `User`. (`UserCustomEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport`) and override `referenceData` in the `RobotFormController` add in the `initBinder` too.

**RobotFormController**

```java
protected void initBinder(HttpServletRequest request, ServletRequestDataBinder binder) {
  SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(getText("date.format"));
  dateFormat.setLenient(false);
  binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, null, 
  new CustomDateEditor(dateFormat, true));
  binder.registerCustomEditor(Long.class, null,
        new CustomNumberEditor(Long.class, null, true));
  binder.registerCustomEditor(User.class, new UserEditor(userManager));
}

// ...
protected Map referenceData(HtppServletRequest request) throws Exception {
  Map ownersMap = new HashMap();
  ownersMap.put("owners", userManager.getUsers();
  return ownersMap;
}
```

`userManager.getUsers();` return a List of Users.

UserEditor (maybe here is my error).

```java
public class UserEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport {

  private final UserManager userManager;
  protected final transient Log log = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

  public UserEditor(UserManager userManager) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    this.userManager = userManager;
  }

  @Override
  public void setAsText(String text) throws IllegalArgumentException {
   if (text != null && text.length() > 0) {
     try {
          User user = userManager.getUser(new String (text));
                    super.setValue(user);
         } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
         }
      } else {
            super.setValue(null);
            }
     }

  @Override
  public String getAsText() {
    User user = (User) super.getValue();
    return  (user != null ? (user.getId()+"").toString(): "");
  }

}
```

**robotForm.jsp**

```java
<form:select path="owner" itemValue="id" itemLabel="name" items="${owners}"
</form:select>
```

I get a `NullPointerException` in the 
`ownersMap.put("owners", userManager.getUsers();` line of the `referenceData` method.

**Edit:**

**UserManagerImpl**

```java
@Service(value = "userManager")
public class UserManagerImpl implements UserManager {
@Autowired
UserDao dao;

public void setUserDao(UserDao dao) {
    this.dao = dao;
}

public List getUsers() {
    return dao.getUsers();
}

public User getUser(String userId) {
    return dao.getUser(Long.valueOf(userId));
}

public void saveUser(User user) {
    dao.saveUser(user);
}

public void removeUser(String userId) {
    dao.removeUser(Long.valueOf(userId));
}
}
```

**Robot.java**

```java
public class Robot extends BaseObject {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1932852212232780150L;
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private Date birthday;
    private User owner;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Date getBirthday() {
        return birthday;
    }
    public void setBirthday(Date birthday) {
        this.birthday = birthday;
    }
    public User getOwner() {
        return owner;
    }
    public void setOwner(User owner) {
        this.owner = owner;
    }
}
```

Comment: userManager is null. Are you instantiating or injecting it? Show us the full code.

Comment: Edited, the RobotFormController has an instance of the userManager.

Comment: Where is your RobotFormController? and show us the bean configuration as well.

Comment: Edited. Add Robot.java. User.java looks like Robot.java.
Robot.hbm.xml (Hibernate Configuration) have a many-to-one relationship.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I am seeing why you are having a null in there is that `'userManager'` has not been instantiated.

You can check if it has been through `(userManager == null)`.
Your code looks good to me, not looking into the logic. I think your configuration of Spring's IoC is the problem here.

Can you post your *.xml files.
This would help out solve your problems.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I could fix it with a robotManager. I used the robotManager to take the users. (robotManager.getUsers() method).
I think my mistake was not associated the UserManager with the RobotFormController. Or at least that's what I read.